# named_scope does not show correct columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

## Update

I am trying to do is select specific columns and use aliases on them, and use it in a named_scope. I want to use aliases because later on I'll use this as an idea when I try to join many tables, based on the SQL that I have created.

**Edit**:
Im running in Rails 2.3.8 and Ruby 1.8.7

---

Here is my named_scope...

```
named_scope :prog_result,:select => "users.id AS 'user_id', users.username AS 'username', users.lastname AS 'lastname', users.firstname AS 'firstname', departments.name AS 'department', versions.number AS 'version'", 
                         :joins => {:department => :version}
```

And when I try to call it in console `User.prog_result` the result is this...

```
[#<User username: "respondent1", lastname: "res", firstname: "pon">, #<User username: "2222", lastname: "Numero", firstname: "Dos">]
```

`User.prog_result.find(2)` 2 is the id of the user "respondent1", the result of `User.prog_result.inspect` is this

```
"[#<User username: \"respondent1\", lastname: \"res\", firstname: \"pon\">, #<User username: \"2222\", lastname: \"Numero\", firstname: \"Dos\">]"
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `User.prog_result` in the console, you are really calling `User.prog_result.inspect` The console is displays the result by calling `#inspect` on the result object.

If instead you called `User.prog_result.class` in the console, you'd see that it was an `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope`.

If you poke inside these objects that are being returned, you'll probably find what you are expecting.

```
User.prog_result.first.department => first joined department.name
User.prog_result.last.version   => last joined version.number
```

Both named scopes and passing `:joins`, `:conditions` and `:select` are deprecated in Rails 3.1, so you should probably not be developing new code with them unless you are on Rails 2.3.x. You'll want to do something like this:

```
User.joins(:department => :version).
select("users.id AS 'user_id', users.username AS 'username', users.lastname AS 'lastname', users.firstname AS 'firstname', departments.name AS 'department', versions.number AS 'version'")
```

Comment: Sorry about that!, I'm running Rails 2.3.8 I edited my question. You're correct about `User.prog_result.class` it does return `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` in console, and also about poking inside it. But when I tried to get the department it returns `nil` idk why, but with my previous code I used `User.find_by_sql()` I got their departments..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quit sure about your question, But I assume you are looking at a User object and rails returns an array.

If thats the case, named_scope will always return an array (just like you do a User.find_all())

even if there is only one record

Hope i got your question right ..

thanks and regards

sameera